# QVideoWidget in full-screen mode no longer responds to hotkeys or mouse wheel

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, qvideowidget, qshortcut

Using QVideoWidget in PySide2 (although the python part may not be significant).  I've set up my hotkeys using QShortcut, and it all works great.  When I press 'F' to enter full-screen mode that works too, but then I can't leave.  None of my hotkeys or mouse event handlers work.  I end up stuck in full-screen mode.

Is there a way to allow it to respond even in full-screen mode?  Have I gone about creating my hotkeys the wrong way?

This example demonstrates the issue:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._fullscreen = False
        self.movie_display = QVideoWidget(self)
        self.movie_handler = QMediaPlayer()
        self.movie_handler.setVideoOutput(self.movie_display)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.movie_display)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        QShortcut(QKeySequence(QtConsts.Key_F), self, self.toggle_fullscreen)
        s = 'test.webm'
        s = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), s)
        local = QUrl.fromLocalFile(s)
        media = QMediaContent(local)
        self.movie_handler.setMedia(media)
        self.movie_handler.play()

    def toggle_fullscreen(self):
        self._fullscreen = not self._fullscreen
        self.movie_display.setFullScreen(self._fullscreen)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the shortcut is set in the window but when full-screen is set in the `QVideoWidget` 2 windows are created: The original window and the window where the `QVideoWidget` is in full-screen. One possible solution is to set the QShortcut in the `QVideoWidget` or establish that the context of the QShortcut is `Qt::ApplicationShortcut`:

```
import os

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._fullscreen = False
        self.movie_display = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget()

        self.movie_handler = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(
            self, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface
        )
        self.movie_handler.setVideoOutput(self.movie_display)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.movie_display)
        QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_F),
            self.movie_display,
            self.toggle_fullscreen,
        )
        # or
        """QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_F),
            self,
            self.toggle_fullscreen,
            context=QtCore.Qt.ApplicationShortcut
        )"""

        file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "test.webm")
        media = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file))
        self.movie_handler.setMedia(media)
        self.movie_handler.play()

    def toggle_fullscreen(self):
        self._fullscreen = not self._fullscreen
        self.movie_display.setFullScreen(self._fullscreen)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```